# Yii2 сложный SQL запрос

Tags: yii2

Есть SQL запрос:

```
SELECT * ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `likes` WHERE postId = id) AS likes FROM `posts`;
```

Как мне поместить этот запрос в модель, что бы возвращался объект, который можно будет поместить в GridView.

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ:**
Придумал вот такой костыль. Но хотелось бы сделать все "правильно".

```
public static function getVideos()
{
    return static::find()->select([
        '* ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `likes` WHERE videoId = id) AS likes'
      ])->asArray();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подзапросы можно использовать таким образом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Источник: [Yii2, построитель запросов select()](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-db-query-builder.html#select)

Answer (score 1):

При объявлении связей вы можете модифицировать ваш запрос практически(!) как-угодно.
В вашем случае, скорее, всего это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
public function getLikesCount()
{
    return $this->hasOne('models\\Like', ['videoId' => 'id'])
        ->select(['COUNT(*) as value', 'videoId'])->groupBy('videoId')
        ->asArray();
}
```

videoId в селекте нужно чтоб потом AR мог присоединить выбранные данные к основным моделям.
В итоге, вы сможете получить нужное значение в GridView и подобных виджетах как **likesCount.value**